# Encountering an infinite loop when using Scanner.hasNextInt();

Tags: java, loops, while-loop, infinite

So the code that I have here is:

```
     public int getCount()
     {
       Scanner s1 = new Scanner(line);
       int count=0; 
       while(s1.hasNextInt());
        {
           int x = s1.nextInt();
           count++;
        }
       return count;
       }
```

I don't understand why i'm getting the infinite loop when I am using .nextInt(); and following all of my notes.

If any of you could help I would be very thankful.

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the semi-colon after the while. Because of the semi-colon, the block after the `while` is an independent block as the `while` loop terminates at the `;` with an empty statement. The while condition always stays `true` and thus the infinite loop.

```
while(s1.hasNextInt())
```

Comment: Oh my gosh. *Facepalm* I can't believe I forgot to do that. Thanks a lot, hopefully I don't make anymore mistakes like that.

I've been working on this for so long too! Haha

Comment: No problem! It happens quite a lot when someone stretches too much! :) Happy learning.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `;` after this line:

```
while(s1.hasNextInt());
```

In this case, `;` acts as an empty statement, so you have a `while`-loop containing an empty statement, and after that a block between `{` and `}`, which will never be executed because the loop with the empty statement repeats forever.